# GFCI ground fault error and will not trip when tested

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci, replacement

I'm installing a gfci in a bathroom replacing a regular outlet. Initially it was tripping when the adjoining light switch was flipped. I moved that switch feed to the line side to fix that issue but my gfci tester shows ground fault error and will not trip the gfci when test is activated.

Comment: Do you have a ground wire? Picture of the wiring would help. Does the actual GFCI test button (as opposed to an external testing device) work?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes, it is grounded appropriately. And yes, the test button on the outlet trips it off.

Comment: Typical (but likely not 100%) situation of a GFCI tester not tripping a *functioning* GFCI is if the ground is not good, because the tester works by taking a bit of the hot current and routing it to ground (instead of to neutral). Picture of the wiring would still help.

Comment: What is this "GFCI tester" gadget you're suing?

Answer (score 1):

Your GFCI tester is correct with an open ground it will not trip the GFCI

the test button on the receptacle will function,  this is normal for a standard 2 wire circuit.

The GFCI won’t create a ground it detects an imbalance in the current between the hot and neutral, more than 5 milli amps or 5ma imbalance will trip the GFCI’s circuitry and turn off the power.

Why is the plug in tester not working? The plug in tester places a resistor from the hot leg to the ground lug and created a imbalance. No ground or open ground and the tester can’t create the imbalance.

Is your circuit safe?  It could be. This is normal for a 2 wire circuit and as safe from electrical shock as a 3 wire protected by a GFCI.

If you have a true ground that is open you should find out where ground was lost.
But if a 2 wire put the “no equipment ground” sticker on the receptacle and it is code compliant even in 2021.

Comment: I agree with this as the likely diagnosis and a good explanation. But OP in a comment said *Yes, it is grounded appropriately.*

Comment: Yes, the OP did say that. That doesn’t mean it’s true. #1 you have to be skeptical about such judgements made by people asking questions like this (if they were actually qualified to make that judgment they wouldn’t be asking the question). #2 it’s also contradicted by the magic 8-ball measurements.